# HDA Intel PCH ALC257 microphone records only noise

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have Lenovo IdeaPad S540 with HDA Intel PCH ALC257 running under Debian 10 Buster. Sadly, the microphone does not work properly. At the beginning, PulseAudio did not even recognized the microphone. It was cured with following instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone) under 'Microphone not detected by PulseAudio' and then adding `options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=laptop-dmic` into `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. However, now that I have a microphone, it does not record anything except pure white noise regardless of any input (no exaggeration here). I would really appreciate any help with the matter.

Comment: Try installing the kernel from Debian SID - see if it works. If it doesn't install kernel 5.8.1, if it still doesn't work, file a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/